# Ошибка EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу нарисовать котика, а мне выдаёт ошибку

```
print(r'/\_/\')
print(r'>^,^<')
print(r'/ \')
print(r'|_|)_/')
```

**Ошибка:**

```
    print(r'/\_/\')
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ошибка переводится так: "(встретился) конец строки кода (EOL - end of line) при сканировании литерала строки". Такая ошибка обычно возникает, когда строка вообще не закрыта (нет закрывающей кавычки), например:

```
print('abc)
```

У вас эта ошибка происходит из-за того, обратные слеши в конце строк  экранируют кавычку (делают кавычку частью строки, а не признаком ее конца). Чтобы это не происходило, нужно обратные слеши в конце строк удвоить (но убрать r, иначе в конце так и будет выводиться удвоенный обратный слеш):

```
print('/\_/\\')
print('>^,^<')
print(' / \\')
print(' |_|)_/')
```

Или добавить пробелы после обратных слешей:

```
print(r'/\_/\ ')
print(r'>^,^<')
print(r' / \ ')
print(r' |_|)_/')
```

В строках добавил еще начальные пробелы, чтобы голова котика не была смещена.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Особенно за заботу!