# Питон добавляет лишний "\" в строку с путём файла

Tags: python, текст, python-3.6, форматирование

У меня есть файл в котором через пробел записаны пути до файлов, которые моя программа должна "скрыть". Строка внутри файла выглядит так:
[image: файл с путями до файлов]

Вот участок кода где я этот самый файл открываю, а затем делаю из его содержимого список через **split()**:
[image: Код]

Результат очень странны. первый **print()** выводит то-же, что и написано в файле (Всё верно):

```
"U:\FileHider\test.txt U:\FileHider\test2.txt"
```

Второй-же **print()**, как я и хотел - выводит список из путей до файлов, но пути до файлов в нём искажены: в них заместо одного "*\*", их 2 - "*\\*".
Вот такой вывод у второго **print()**:

```
['U:\\FileHider\\test.txt', 'U:\\FileHider\\test2.txt']
```

P.S - Для того чтобы на это сайте поставить 2 "*\*" - мне пришлось на самом деле поставить 4. Я понимаю что это для форматирования, но как от этого избавиться? Неужели писать отдельный участок кода для преобразования этого в нормальный вид?

Comment: Ключевая фраза для гугления "экранированный последовательности" , "экранированные символы", "escaped characters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sl = ['U:\\FileHider\\test.txt', 'U:\\FileHider\\test2.txt']
res = [x.replace('\\', '\') for x in sl]
```

ВНИМАНИЕ! код не рабочий специально, что бы подумать. вот )

Comment: а вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076546/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-eol-while-scanning-string-literal

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение. Хочу добавить, что ваш код использовать не нужно в данном случае - два " \" - было не более чем отображением в консоли функцией print. На самом же деле в списке строка имела нормальный вид с 1-им "\"

Comment: Я использую r перед строкой, чтобы не было исключения. Вот так - r"blabla\bla\bla". Так исключения не будет

Answer (score 3):

Решено. У кого тоже самое - это просто форматирование текста функцией print() в питоне. Если Print выводит что у вас в словаре написано что-то такое:

```
myDict = {'U:\\FileHider\\tmp.dat': 'test.txt', 'U:\\FileHider\\tmp1.dat': 'test2.txt'}
```

Это не более чем отображение в консоли. Вы должны использовать всё ту-же нормальную запись с 1-им бекслешем
myDict["U:\FileHider\tmp.dat"] (С 1-им бекслешем).

Всё нормально

Comment: Вот как раз print выводит один \. А если вы набираете код, то вместо одного используйте два, Что бы строку закрыть. Иначе строка будет не закрыта и "вывалится" исключение...

Comment: `sl = ['U:\\FileHider\\test.txt', 'U:\\FileHider\\test2.txt']`
`res = [x.replace('\\', '/') for x in sl]`
`print(sl[1])`
`print(res)`
U:\FileHider\test2.txt
['U:/FileHider/test.txt', 'U:/FileHider/test2.txt']